# Read both strings and raw bytes from standard input in java

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a program which will be receiving information from an external source via System.in.  There are two input modes: line mode and raw mode.  During line mode, input is simply a series of UTF-8 strings, each terminated with a line feed character.  At some point while in line mode, I will receive notification that I am about to receive N bytes of raw data.  At that point the input switches to raw mode and I receive exactly N bytes of raw binary data, which are not valid UTF-8 characters.  After this point, it returns to line mode.

Is there a way to easily switch between reading strings and reading raw data?  My only thought is to read an InputStream byte by byte and translate to characters as I go.  Are there any ways to wrap System.in with multiple types of input streams?  I feel like reading from two different wrappers would cause problems.

**(FIXED) Update:**

I tried parsifal's suggestion, but am running into a problem.  To simulate the switching input modes, I modified my test harness.  (I realized that another process I have will eventually need to output this way as well.)  I don't know if the problem is caused by the send or receive end.  When I switch between output modes, it doesn't seem to be reading in the bytes properly.  Also, it's always the same byte values that appear.  Here are some code excerpts:

**FIX:**  The problem was that apparently you can't switch from the OutputStreamWriter to OutputStream too quickly.  I added a 1ms sleep command before sending the raw bytes, and the problem is solved!

Test Harness:

```
Process p = processList.get(pubName); //Stored list of started Processes
OutputStream o = p.getOutputStream(); //Returns OutputStream which feeds into stdin
out = new OutputStreamWriter(runPublisher.getOutputStream());

byte[] payload = new byte[25];
out.write("\nPAYLOAD\nRAW\n"); // "RAW\n" signals raw mode
out.write(String.valueOf(payload.length) + "\n");
out.flush();
Thread.sleep(1); //This fixed the problem I was having.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(payload));
o.write(payload);
o.flush();
```

Client:

```
InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

while(true){
    try{
        if((chIn = inReader.read())!= -1){
            if(chIn == (int)'\n'){
                if(rawMode){
                    if(strIn.equals("ENDRAW"))
                        rawMode = false;
                    else{
                        System.out.println(strIn);
                        //Exception on next line
                        int rawSize = Integer.parseInt(strIn);
                        payload = new byte[rawSize];
                        int t = System.in.read(payload);
                        System.out.println("Read " + t + " bytes");
                        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(payload));
                    }
                }else if(strIn.startsWith("RAW")){
                    rawMode = true;
                }else {
                    // Do other things
                }
                strIn = "";
            }else
                strIn += (char)chIn;
        }else
            break;
    }catch(IOException e){break;}
}
```

And the outputs (prior to adding Sleep statement) look like this:

Test Harness:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Client:
25
Read 9 bytes
[83, 72, 85, 84, 68, 79, 87, 78, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    at myClass.handleCommand(myClass.java:249)
```

Comment: How user can type raw bytes e.g. 0x00 via keyboard?!

Comment: Can you guarantee a newline before the raw bytes?

Comment: @YasserZamani, it isn't coming from a keyboard.  It is being controlled by another program, and commands are coming through stdin.

Comment: @parsifal, Yes, the external source has explicitly defined a protocol which includes line breaks after every command, including the RAW command.

Comment: @DavidK - OK, that will make your dispatch easier: simply read from the `Reader` until you get the linebreak, then dispatch what you've accumulated.

Comment: In response to your comment, is this correct? `System.in.read(payload);` You don't show where you construct `inReader`, but is it really around `System.in`?

Comment: @parsifal Yes to both. `InputStream.read(byte[])` should read in the same number of bytes as the size of `byte[]` and return the number of bytes successfully read.  Also, I filled my array being sent, and discovered that it is not successfully reading any bytes. (Edits added to main post)

Comment: @DavidK - translating the bytes received, I get "SHUTDOWN\n". Given that this is an intelligible word, fully received, I have to believe that your device is not actually sending the data that you think it is. Or that you're not parsing what you think you are. I've recommended an alternative implementation that I think it simpler. Aside from that, my only recommendation is that you wrap `System.in` with some sort of debugging stream (for example, Jakarta Commons IO has a `TeeInputStream` that would let you copy everything into a file/array that you could then examine with a hexdump).

Comment: @parsifal - "SHUTDOWN\n" is actually a command I send later in the code.  I tried stepping through the code and discovered that having a pause between the OutputStreamWriter and the OutputStream fixes the problem.  All is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `System.in` with an `InputStreamReader` that specifies "utf-8" encoding, and then read character-by-character. Accumulate characters into a `StringBuilder` and dispatch whenever appropriate (nomially when you see `'\n'`, but possibly based on a test of the builder).

When you want to read binary data, just read from the underlying `InputStream` (`System.in`). The `InputStreamReader` performs translation as-needed, and does not buffer data.

You do *not* want to use any sort of buffered stream or reader in the stack. This will eliminate any opportunity to use a `readLine()` method, at least if you confine yourself to the JDK classes.

---

Edit based on your latest updates:

I think that your switching between raw and cooked mode is a bit suspicious. If I were to implement this, I'd create two primitive operations, `String readLine()` and `byte[] readData(length)`. The first accumulates characters up to a newline, the second reads a fixed buffer. Then your main loop looks something like this:

```
InputStream in = // ...
Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(in, "USASCII");  // or whatever encoding you use

while (true) {
    String command = readLine(rd );
    if (command .equals("RAW")) {
        int length = Integer.parseInt(readLine(rd ));
        byte[] data = readData(in , length);
        if (! readLine(rd ).equals("ENDRAW")) {
            throw // an exception that indicates protocol violation
        }
    }
    else // process other commands
}
```

I would also wrap the whole thing up in an object, which is constructed around the stream, and perhaps uses callbacks to dispatch the data packets.

Comment: I'll give this a try and mark as an answer if it works (which might be a while).  Thanks for the tip on buffering - I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: Tried this and ran into a problem.  Could you take a look at my update and see what you think?

Comment: This worked when I was communicating between my own Java processes, but when I tried to communicate with the external source, I had to switch to byte-by-byte reading from System.in

Answer (score 1):

the best bet is probably to just read byte-by-byte (using `System.in.read()`)into a buffer until you hit the UTF-8 line feed byte 0x0A, then translate that byte buffer into a string (using `new String(byte[] bytes, "UTF-8")`).

note that `read()` called on a InputStream will return an int with a value from 0 to 255, you'll need to cast it into a byte.  You can accumulate bytes in a Collection of some sort, then use standard Collection framework tools to convert it to an array for consumption by the String constructor.

When you see the indicator that its going to switch over (presumably some sort of in-stream signalling, certain specific bytes), then switch to your raw byte reading code.

Comment: parsifal's answer worked when I was communicating with my own Java process, but I had to switch to this method when communicating with the external program (written in C++)